# Data frame printing in R Markdown : how to hide column type?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

When I print a data frame with R Markdown (html_document), I get the following table (see image below) with the following example code :

---

````
title: "Motor Trend Car Road Tests"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r}
mtcars
```
````

[image: Printed Data Frame]

Is there a way to hide the column types corresponding to the yellow highligting in the image?

Comment: Looks like that's the price of paged df printing, http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#paged_printing However, you might be able to hide it with fancy custom css, hiding "pagedtable-header-type" divs or something.

Comment: simple option is to use `knitr::kable(mtcars)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option - Use the DT package.

````
---
title: "Motor Trend Car Road Tests"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
--- 

```{r}
DT::datatable(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Sometimes when the size of the data frame is really big, `datatable` throws an error. Do you have any suggestions on how to display in that case without taking a sample of the data?

Comment: I have not run into that but you could try reactable (https://glin.github.io/reactable/index.html) which is actually my preferred method these days.